# Simplification behaviour of subscript expression: is this correct?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, subscript

Why does the code (Mathematica version 10.0.2.0, Linux x86-64):

```
Subscript[Subscript[S,i],j] Subscript[Subscript[S,i],j] // Simplify
```

output the expression:

> $(S_i)^2_j$

Is this the expected output? If so, why? <strike>And how can I prevent `Simplify` from touching the expression above if this is the correct behaviour?</strike>

**Edit 1:**

To be clear, what I mean is this: the output of the expression looks "ambiguous" to me. If I want to interpret the subscript as an operation on `S`, then the simplified expression is not equivalent to the original one. Why doesn't Mathematica output:

> $(S_{ij})^2$

instead? Can I make Mathematica output this instead?

**Edit 2:**

This questions is not about the Mathematica code I posted above because I want to interpret the subscripts as a particular operation, and in the code above I can convert to a form that is handled better in calculations than subscripts. What I want to know is why Mathematica outputs the code as $(S_i)^2_j$, when my suggestion of $(S_{ij})^2$ seems more logical and "safer" (in the sense that it preserves more of the structure of the original form).

**Edit 3:**

To better display my intent, I'll explain that I want to interpret the index as notation for an operation, $d_i$ acting on an object $S$. In Mathematica I write it as `d[S,i]`, but since I may have up to 6 (and potentially more) $d$ operations on one object, I want to *display* this more succinctly as $S_i$. To this effect I execute:

```
expr //. d[S_, i_] -> Subscript[S,i]
```

when displaying my expressions. A nice side effect is that I can also *enter* expressions in this notation by converting back to the functional form before I do my calculations proper:

```
expr = displayexpr //. Subscript[S_, i_] -> d[S,i]
(* calculations on expr... *)
```

Now, my expressions are long and multitudinous, so when I simplified expressions like

```
Subscript[Subscript[S,i],j] Subscript[Subscript[S,i],j]
```

I was given the output:

> $(S_i)^2_j$

which threw me since at first glance it seems to tell me I have expressions of the form:

```
Subscript[Subscript[S,i]^2, j]
```

I can understand what Mathematica is doing, I just wonder if it is the best way to display its expressions...

Comment: The `FullForm` of your output is `Power[Subscript[Subscript[S, i], j], 2]`. What would you expect the output to be?

Comment: @Bill: I do need to use the expression, so `HoldForm` might not be useful.

Comment: @Karsten7.: OK, I see what the expression is trying to say, but it reads like the j-th component of $S_i$ squared. I guess I want the expression to come out as $(S_{ij})^2$. I'll edit the question to make that more explicit.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using `Subscript[S, i, j]`. [This tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TypingSubscripts.html) might be helpful.

Comment: @Karsten7.: `Subscript[S,i,j]` outputs: $S_{i,j}$ and I don't want the comma to appear since it's clutter and there will eventually be a lot of subscripts in my code :) Can I print an invisible comma by using the `Subscript` function only once?

Comment: Since no one has mentioned it yet: it is highly recommended not to use `Subscript`s for calculations purposes; only use `Subscript` for display purposes. They *can* be used for calculation purposes, but there's some strange subtleties arising with their use that even *somewhat* experienced users can't predict. It is recommended to use things like `S[i,j]` instead. In that case, your problem with be resolved automatically, and if you want, you can choose to display quantities like `S[i,j]` as subscripted symbols later.

Comment: @march: I have heard this already, yes :) I wasn't planning on using the subscripts in calculations, only to clean up the expressions when looking at them. (I change subscripts to functions before I do calculations). I guess you've answered my question: `Simplify` should be considered a "calculation". I'll do the `Simplify` on the unadulterated expressions and then change to subscripts. Thanks!

Comment: @Xavier: this would make using the expression in calculations again difficult wouldn't it? I mean: once you "stringify" the expression, it's not an expression that can be manipulated as easily again, right? Can I do it without strings, or, more usefully, am I wrong? can I change strings back into expressions and then manipulate them?

Comment: @Xavier: Well, I guessed so. Thanks for the suggestions anyway: there's lots there that I've never seen before and no doubt will find useful somewhere else!

Comment: @Xavier: I think Mathematica also shifts the subscripts down in the last form, which I didn't notice at first, but is clearer with a third subscript: `Subscript[Subscript[Subscript[S,i],j],k]`. Regardless, even with the parenthesis form, I think $((S_i)_j)^2$ would be better in order to make clear that the subscript operations are higher in the order of operations as is usual in mathematics. But, it's a fair point :)

Comment: Related: *Avoid using subscripted symbols in your code* point of [Basic syntax issues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/14303)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notation and preliminary remarks**

The form of the outputs depends on the objects to which `Subscript` is applied. In the situation at stake, we should differentiate between the cases

- $S_{ij}$, `Subscript[S, i j]`
- $(S_i)_j$, `Subscript[Subscript[S, i], j]`
- $S_{i_j}$, `Subscript[S, Subscript[i, j]]`

which display respectively as

[image]

We can see that the line on which the index $j$ is written differs for each output.

---

**About the question**

1. *First part, and edits 1 and 2 of the question*

Considering the square of the above expressions,

```
Subscript[S, i j] Subscript[S, i j]
Subscript[Subscript[S, i], j] Subscript[Subscript[S, i], j]
Subscript[S, Subscript[i, j]] Subscript[S, Subscript[i, j]]
```

we have the displays

[image]

With the introduced notation, the form $(S_{ij})^2$ mentioned in the question (see **Edit 1** and **Edit 2**) is related to the expression `Subscript[S, i j] Subscript[S, i j]` and not to

```
Subscript[Subscript[S, i], j] Subscript[Subscript[S, i], j]
```

The latter is related instead to the form $((S_i)_j)^2$ and the associated output (see screenshot above) can then be considered as the expected output.

2. *Edit 3 of the question*

> I can understand what Mathematica is doing, I just wonder if it is the best way to display its expressions

I think it amounts to how one would define "best way". It may be only a matter of taste in the end. Here the set of rules used for the display of subscripts is complicated, but (a) it is self-consistent when several subscripts and indices are used in different orders and (b) it reduces the number of parentheses used to avoid having a too cumbersome notation (see next section below).

This being said, if you prefer you can define your own set of display rules by using `Format` as suggested by march in his [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101538/31159), or by using `MakeBoxes`.

Considering for instance the example taken from your comment,

> I think for `Subscript[Subscript[S, i]^2, j]` they should display $(S^2_i)_j$

you could use

```
Format[Subscript[Subscript[S_, i_]^2, j_]] := 
   DisplayForm@SubscriptBox[ RowBox[ {"(", SubscriptBox[S, i]^2, ")"} ], j ]
```

to get $(S^2_i)_j$ when evaluating `Subscript[Subscript[S_, i_]^2, j_]`.

---

**Further comments**

Why do we have one set of parentheses for the output of $((S_i)_j)^2$? We may think of having instead (a) no parentheses, or (b) two sets.

(a) We saw at the beginning that the position of the index $j$ depends on the object to which `Subscript` applies, so we may be able in principle to infer the form of the input by looking at the position of the index.

Parentheses are used here to avoid ambiguities with another case for which the down position of the index $j$ is the same,

```
Subscript[Subscript[S, i], j] Subscript[Subscript[S, i], j]
Subscript[Subscript[S, i] Subscript[S, i], j]
```

[image]

(b) The idea of not having several sets of parentheses is to avoid the notation being too cumbersome I think, so by default only one set of parentheses is displayed.

We may onsider for instance the square of an expression with three indices, e.g. `Subscript[Subscript[Subscript[S, i], j], k]`, for which we have only one set.

The rule seems to be the following. When a power applies to a `Subscript` expression, the first argument of this expression is enclosed between parentheses, unless it does not contain itself an indice, in which case the parentheses are removed.

For instance the two last expressions above can be rewritten

```
Subscript[Subscript[S, i], j]^2
Subscript[Subscript[S, i]^2, j]
```

The first will display a set of parentheses around `Subscript[S, i]`, and the second around `S`. Since `S` is not an expression with indices, the parentheses are removed. This is what we see in the last screenshot, and it can be checked that this is what happens in the previous one.

Comment: I think this is indeed the logic being used. However, to the designers I would make the point that if they happy to leave the position of the j index as discriminating the three cases above, even when it is subtle, they should do the same when it is squared: letting the j index alone discriminate between them. The brackets on $(S_i)^2_j$ makes it seem something else is being displayed -- namely that the square is acting first and then the index (i.e. $((S_i)^2)_j$. I think the departure from consistency is what threw me. But maybe that's just me :)

Comment: I think for `Subscript[Subscript[S, i]^2, j]` they should display $(S_i^2)_j$ and for `Subscript[Subscript[S^2, i], j]` they should display $(S^2)_{ij}$ (but with the j lower down than the i). But, again, maybe that's just me :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want

```
Subscript[S, i, j] Subscript[S, i, j]
```

[image: form]

or

```
Subscript[S, i j] Subscript[S, i j]
```

[image: form2]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (in particular, I didn't know you could do the second form!), but I'd like to keep the two subscript operations distinct so that I can convert the subscripts to functions and then do calculations on objects that are not subscripts :) I'll make this clearer in the question...

Comment: @Zorawar. To keep the subscripts distinct for computation purposes. you want the 1st form. The 2nd form is only useful formatting symbolic output. The subscripts are interpreted as `i*j` in computation.

Comment: @Zorawar One can create an output similar to the 2nd form, but without a multiplication of subscripts, using `Subscript[S, Row[{i, j}]]`.

Comment: @Karsten7. Good point, but again not useful for computation.

Comment: But always convertible to a form more suitable for computation, whereas `Subscript[S, i j]` can't be converted after evaluation if `i` and `j` have for example a numerical value.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Ah, yes of course. Thanks for the correction! And thank you again for the answer, but I think the essential answer to my question is: "using subscripts can be unintuitive: treat simplification as a calculation and do that before converting to subscripts," which march gave in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use quantities like `S[i, j]` for calculations (including applying `Simplify`) and use `Subscript`s *only* for display purposes. If you have a simplified expression `expr` involving quantities like `S[i, j]` that you would like to format nicely, do

```
expr /. A_[i_, j_] :> Subscript[A, i j]
```

at the end of the calculation. (This particular choice of `Subscript` format was suggested by [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) in the [answer above](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101455/29734).)

Note that you can also choose to format everything with the `Head` `S` as a subscript, so that it will always *display* as a subscripted symbol, but under the hood, it will still be `S[i, j]`. We can do this as follows:

```
Format[S[a__]] := DisplayForm@SubscriptBox["S", StringJoin @@ ToString /@ {a}]
```

**Update in response to Edit 3 of the question**

Edit 3 of the question suggests to me that `Format`ting is the correct way to go. Since in Edit 3, a `d` notation is used, I suggest using:

```
Format[d[A_, j__]] := DisplayForm@SubscriptBox[ToString@A, StringJoin @@ ToString /@ {j}]
```

I didn't note this before, but if you execute this *before* any calculations, anything of the form `d[A_, j__]` will display as a subscripted symbol.

Comment: Actually, interestingly, simplifying my expressions before converting to index form (see my edit no. 3) gives exactly the same expression as if I simplified _after_ converting to index form. That is, for my purposes, when I simplify makes no difference. (Of course, other operations may be not save to do after converting to index form.) It seems I just have to get used to the way Mathematica decides to display its expressions.

Comment: @Zorawar. Your Edit 3 suggests to me that you shouldn't go back and forth between the different forms. I suggest you use `Format`ting instead, as in my answer. Since you use this `d` notation, I have updated the post with that formatting choice.

Comment: I don't go back and forth during any intermediate steps. That would be asking for trouble! Only ever at the first step of entering inputs, and the last step of display outputs. But, the `Format` option might be the right way to go. Thanks.

Comment: @Xavier. Yes, thanks for heads-up! Fixed.